# Create a read-only column that can get updated only by code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Is there a way to create a column to be readonly to the user, but updatable by the script/code?

i know with update statement whatever values the users will put will get overwritten anyways, but it would be nice to make it read-only to the user in the first place.

for example, if i want to create a `PROCESS_STATUS` column, in which the script inserts success or failure status as value, and this value is read-only to the user of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of the table. Grant your users read-only access to the view, and no access at all to the table.

This is exactly the sort of thing that [Server and Database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/server-and-database-roles-in-sql-server) exist to manage.

Comment: Well I want them to have regular access to change/ update other columns. I only want this one column read only